# Invitation list for user no Invitation Object

Tags: node.js, google-classroom

I was trying to get a list of invitations of the requesting user assuming that the user already invited as teacher/student from a certain class. Using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D) with a userId of "me", but the response is:

```
{"nextPageToken": "IgIQAg"}
```

I'm expecting to get all the invitations of the requesting/authenticated user. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

#### Looks like what you are experiencing might in fact be a bug.

There is this open issue on Google's Issue Tracker with regards to it. I suggest you star this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182284916) and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it.

Moreover, I suggest you double check if the user on behalf of which you are making the request does *indeed* have any invitations.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually tried using the domain type of account and already getting the list of invitations of the requesting user, what I'm encountering right now is when trying to accept the invitation on behalf of the invited user, given the id of the invitation, I'm getting
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
Though when trying to get the details of the invitation via get api, I'm getting the expected response.